# fsharp assign value by referencing via square brackets

Tags: f#

For fsharp Array we can do the following:

```
let tt = Array.zeroCreate 10 
tt.[5] <- 4
Console.WriteLine("{0}", tt.[5])
```

Result will be 4

I want to implement my own class that provides similar interface.
As a sample, I have wrote this:

```
type MyByteArray = class
    val Data : byte[]

    new (size) =
        {
            Data = Array.init size (fun x -> byte(x))
        }

    member this.Item (id) = 
        this.Data.[id]
end

let test = MyByteArray 5
Console.WriteLine("{0}", test.[2]) /// <- this one woks
test.[2] <- 33uy /// <- this one fails
```

This can receive item via [], but can't set it as `item.[id] <- newValue`.

How do I implement such interface?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an indexer with getter and setter like this:

```
member this.Item 
  with get id = this.Data.[id]
  and set id v = this.Data.[id] <- v
```

If I was writing the code, I would also use primary constructor syntax:

```
type MyByteArray(size) =
  let data = Array.init size (fun x -> byte(x))  
  member this.Item 
    with get(id) = data.[id]
    and set id v = data.[id] <- v
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Seems that I still think with C++.